# How to access method outside the project

Tags: android

I wants to access a method in different project.
as example i have called a method as
`Test(name,age);`
In TestActivity
Then how to access this method and it's parameters in
`DemoActivity`
as different project.Please help me.

Comment: Make a [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Comment: Is Your Question "You wanted to create an object Test test=new Test(name,age) from one Activity and call some method of the the object from another Activity (test.someMethod()) in same Application? "

Comment: make the old project as library project and put it in your new project's lib folder whenever you want to call it's method and give the library path , may be it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to configure the build path for the DemoActivity project. In "Projects" tab add TestProject. Now you can access to test project's data.